# Base encoding impossible with leading 0?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to encode a string to base36.

```
static char *decode(unsigned long long value)
{
    char base36[37] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char buffer[14];
    unsigned int offset = sizeof(buffer);

    buffer[--offset] = '\0';
    do {
        buffer[--offset] = base36[value % 36];
    } while (value /= 36);

    return _strdup(&buffer[offset]);
}

int main()
{
    char original[8] = "0XDX3A1";
    unsigned long long encoded = _strtoui64(original, NULL, 36);
    char *decoded = decode(encoded);

    cout << "Original: " << original << " Decoded: " << decoded << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is, while those functions work OK: if the string I am trying to encode has a leading 0 **the decoded string is one character (or more) less than the original**.

How to deal with this?

Comment: How is the code relevant to a question about **decoding**? Show the decoding code and the string you're decoding.

Comment: Are you asking why the value 07 is encoded the same as the value 7?

Comment: I added the code you requested.

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy: when I encode '0A' and then decode it I receive 'A'. I want to receive '0A'.

Comment: Leading zeroes in integers are not significant. For example, 07 is _the same number_ as 7.

Comment: I know this, but "0XDX3" is **NOT** "XDX3".

Comment: What kind of number is 0XDX3?

Comment: @Luka: They are the same value.  If you want the same number of characters every time, then loop for a fixed number of iterations, rather than until your input becomes zero.

Comment: Leading zeros are not significant in any base.  Even if the leading characters are used by convention to indicate base ( eg `0xFF` for hex 255, `007` for octal 7 ), the 0 is part of the representation, not the value.

Comment: I'm confused. Could you _please_ try to post a minimal, working program that still shows the problem, with the observed and the expected output.

Comment: I can loop and add the 0s needed at the start, but this makes error checking harder. Is there any better way? e.g. if I encode this to a higher base?

Comment: @Luka Just include expected and actual outcomes (and show the decoding code).

Comment: @Luka: What error-checking?

Comment: Luka, how exactly are you acquiring the `original` anyway?

Comment: As an aside, I think your `decode` should be called `encode` and vice versa.

Comment: yes, messed up copying. Added complete example.

Comment: How can you use `strdup` when you cannot use `strtoui64`? I had to change it to `_strdup` while preparing the code on my VS Express 2103

Comment: Why does this question has an **impossible** in its title.

Comment: Seems impossible if I don't store the size and the strings are variable length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Introduce a new variable in your main, called `zeroCount` in `main`
- Introduce a 2nd argument to function `decode`, called `zeroCount`
- Count the amount of leading zeroes in the `original` to the `zeroCount` in `main`
- Place zeroes to `buffer[--offset]` until you consume all the `zeroCount` before the `return`

Like this:

```
static char *decode( unsigned long long value, int zeroCount )  
{           // introduced zeroCount argument there ^
    char base36[37] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char buffer[14];
    unsigned int offset = sizeof( buffer );

    buffer[--offset] = '\0';
    do {
        buffer[--offset] = base36[value % 36];
    } while ( value /= 36 );

    while ( zeroCount-- ) buffer[--offset] = '0';   // <-- added this

    return strdup( &buffer[offset] );
}

int main( )
{
    char original[8] = "0XDX3A1";
    unsigned long long encoded = _strtoui64( original, NULL, 36 );

    int zeroCount = 0;                                                  // added
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof original && original[i] == '0'; i++ )   // these
        zeroCount++;                                                    // three

    char *decoded = decode( encoded, zeroCount );   // <-- called along with zeroCount


    cout << "Original: " << original << " Decoded: " << decoded << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since there isn't any apparent rule for the `0` appending behaviour you desire, I had to assume that you'd like to have exact many leading zeroes that the `original` had.

Comment: Not anymore... Well, that was stupid of me, I thought initialized `0`s would print as `0`s, but of course not, they rather have to be made into `'0'`s. Works pretty well right now.

Answer (score 4):

If you decode the string `"01234"` as a base-16 string (for example), you get the integer value `4660` (`0x1234`) -- *exactly* the same integer value you get by decoding the string `"1234"` or `"00001234"` as a base-16 string. By converting the string to an integer, you've thrown away any information about leading zeros.  You've also discarded any information about uppercase vs. lowercase letters, assuming that `A` and `a` represent the same value.

Converting that integer value back to a string isn't going to restore that leading 0 unless you add it explicitly. And if you want to add that leading 0 (or multiple 0s) if and only if they were present in the original string, you're going to have to store that information somehow.

Comment: I see but how is it possible to add the leading 0s if I don't know the size of the string?

Comment: @Luka: You can't.  If you want to recreate the original string, you need to store sufficient information about the original string.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: if I encode this thing as base37 it will be possible, right (by treating '0' as ';' and adding ';' after 'Z')?

Comment: @Luka: Treating `'0'` as `';'`? I don't see how that either makes sense or is helpful.

Comment: if before the encoding I replace all '0' with ';', and after decoding do the opposite, won't I get the expected result, assuming base37?

Comment: @Luka: No matter how you tweak the string to be decoded, `"1234"` and `"01234"` will yield the same number. You can't re-encode that number to two different strings without storing extra information somewhere. You can't store the extra information in the number itself; it has to go somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a function tat takes a string containing a representation of a numeric value and converts it to an `unsigned long long` .  The two string representations '00007' and '7' are both converted to numeric 7, and the leading zeroes are lost.

IF you want, eg, 00000036 to covert to 00000010 in base 36, you'll just have to count the zeroes you want and then decide how many of them to replace ( would it depend on the relative lengths of base 10 and base 36 strings? )

But it seems poor practice in the conversion functions.  better, in my mind, to add leading  zeroes when outputting the value.  As many have commented, they have no significance and should not be part of the conversion logic.

Comment: I think you mean "to add leading zeroes", not "to add trailing zeroes".

Comment: @KeithThompson Wat? Spent a while to see a difference, aren't those two sequence of words identical?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Sorry, I mistyped; I've corrected the comment now. I'm referring to the phrase in the last paragraph.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh, now I get it

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to create a **wrapper** around your method, and pass it a **length** parameter.

Eg.

```
char * wrap_base36enc(int out_len, unsigned long long value){
    char pre_str[MAX_VAL]="", *ans = base36enc(value);
    len -= strlen(ans);

    while(len--){
     strcat(pre_str,"0");
    }
    strcat(pre_str,ans);

    return pre_str;
}
```